# copy all files inside solution to another location after successful build

Tags: c#, copy, project, projects-and-solutions

I'm working on Visual Studio 2008, C# and i have a solution which refers to 3 projects in the same directory. I want to copy all files and folders containied inside the solution to an another location after each successful build. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion a custom [MsBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) Target would be more appropiate here since you could have only one place where the copy is defined and more importantly the copy should probably only be performed when all projects build sucessfully iso a copy of each sucessfully build project.

If you don't like msbuild you could also check out [PSake](http://code.google.com/p/psake/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a [Post Build Event.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx)